# leap year function: 'return leap' is generating an outside function error

Tags: function, syntax-error

I am trying to write a code to identify a leap year; which is if the year is divisible by 4, but not divisible by 100 or 400. I wrote the code below it doesn't execute right- any suggestions?

```
def is_leap(year):
    leap = False

    if year % 4 == 0:
        if year % 100 != 0:
            if year % 400 != 0:
                return True
            else:
                return leap
        else:
            return leap
    else:
        return leap

return leap


is_leap(2000)
```

Comment: Did you forget to tag what language this is?

Comment: I also think your leap year logic is wrong *but not divisible by 100 or 400* should say **but not divisible by 100, but is divisible by 400**. Year 2000 was definitely a leap year

Comment: Strong advice, if applicable: use a library, don't DIY time-related stuff. https://infiniteundo.com/post/25509354022/more-falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time

Comment: This is Python!

Comment: Appreciate the comments Caius- you are right; that fixed it! It was failing the test for 2,000. But once the 400 is changed it works :)